# ES6, Javascript. Declare const, undefined in destructuring assignment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, destructor

```
const Profile = () => (
  <Data data={CURRENT_PLAYER_DATA}>
    {({
      data: {
        currentPlayer: { playerProfile }
      }
    }) => <div>{playerProfile && playerProfile.name}</div>}
  </Data>
);
```

With the code above I got: `playerProfile of undefined!`

```
const Profile = () => (
  <Data data={CURRENT_PLAYER_DATA}>
    {({ data: { currentPlayer: { playerProfile = {} } = {} } = {} }) => (
      <div>{playerProfile && playerProfile.name}</div>
    )}
  </Data>
);
```

With the code above it works, but I don't know why.

And also I need to avoid something like:

```
playerProfile && playerProfile.name
```

How to good understand this flow?

Comment: From where you are getting the data object?

Comment: The data object is Ok. I'm gonna to edit question with data object.

Comment: Why are you trying to create an arrow function there? Where is it called?

Answer (score 1):

Your `currentPlayer` property is `undefined` which means that you are essentially doing

```
var playerProfile = data.currentPlayer.playerProfile;
```

Which will break, since `data.currentPlayer` does not exists. (is `undefined`)

In the second example you are creating a default-value for `currentPlayer`, meaning that `currentPlayer` if `undefined` will be `{}`

Comment: Yes but this is the only way? And why it is undefined if there is data for `currentPlayer`?

Comment: It seems like the `data.currentPlayer` is not resolved on the first render.

Comment: Yes, is there a way to retrieve it on the first render or I need to use the `{}` strategy? Is this the good way? Where am I wrong?

Comment: I can't tell without the source/library of `<Data />`.. But no, there is not a way to do it in the parameter destructing. You could do it in the `render` with `if (!data.currentPlayer) return null; const { currentPlayer: { playerProfile } } = data;....`

Comment: `data` is an object from REST API like this: `{ currentPlayer: { name: "name", surname: "surname", playerProfile: { username: "username" } }`.

Comment: You can in your `<Data>`-component prevent the render-prop call till you have the data from your API.

Comment: Ok, but how? With `if (data)`?

Comment: Yep, something like `if (!data) { return null; } else { return this.props.render(data) }`